# Search Datatable after data loaded

Tags: datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-rails

I'm using DataTables 1.10 in a Rails 4.2 project.  I have the following in a js asset file:

```
var table = $('#ticket_details').DataTable({
stateSave: true,
deferRender: true,
ajax: $('#ticket_details').data('source'),
"columns": [ 
    { "data": "reference_number" },
    { "data": "location" },
    { "data": "title" },
    { "data": "ticket_category", className: "hidden-xs" },
    { "data": "opened_date" },
    { "data": "last_update", className: "hidden-sm hidden-xs"  },
    { "data": "time", className: "hidden-xs", "orderData": 7 },
    { "data": "decimal_time", "searchable": false, className: "hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden"},
    { "data": "open_or_closed", className: "hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden"},
    { "data": "assigned_to", className: "hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" },
    { "data": "icons", className: "hidden-sm hidden-xs"  }]} );      

setInterval( function () {
table.ajax.reload( null, false ); }, 60000 );
```

I'd like to have the table searched on my hidden column which says whether a ticket is Open or Closed.  I've two buttons with some JS behind them to switch between open and closed, but I'd like it to default to open tickets

```
$('#ticket_details').dataTable( {
   "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    table.columns(8).search("Open").draw();
  }
} );

$('#open_toggle').on('click', function () {
      table.columns(8).search("Open").draw();
});

$('#closed_toggle').on('click', function () {
      table.columns(8).search("Closed").draw();
});
```

However when you load the page, the table displays everything.  Surely if I used drawCallback() and then redrew the table it would just create an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a initial search with `search` option [link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search)

Some like:

```
var table = $('#ticket_details').DataTable({
    "search": {
        "search": "Fred"
    },
    stateSave: true,
    deferRender: true,
    ajax: $('#ticket_details').data('source'),
    "columns": [ 
        { "data": "reference_number" },
        { "data": "location" },
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "ticket_category", className: "hidden-xs" },
        { "data": "opened_date" },
        { "data": "last_update", className: "hidden-sm hidden-xs"  },
        { "data": "time", className: "hidden-xs", "orderData": 7 },
        { "data": "decimal_time", "searchable": false, className: "hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden"},
        { "data": "open_or_closed", className: "hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden"},
        { "data": "assigned_to", className: "hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" },
        { "data": "icons", className: "hidden-sm hidden-xs"  }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I'd tried this before.  My problem was that the toggle buttons wouldn't work.  What your solution made me realise was that I needed to set the global table search to an empty string before searching the specific column.  Is there any way to have the initial table definition only search column 10?

Comment: I do not know, maybe with `columns().search()` [link](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().search())